# How to formulate the regression model in R for trials over multiple years?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4

I'm working in a research facility for agriculture where we do a lot of trials that continue over several years.

For the example below i tried to find out how to formulate the regression model correctrly so that "year" is integrated in the model ?

The goal of this trial was to find out which density of wheat plants  brings the most yield. The density of plants is representet by the factor Row_width. Also the factors Fertilizer and Wheat Variety should be considered.
So the example below is a 3 factorial trial (Row_width, Fertilizer, Variety) with 2 gradiatios in each factor. There were 4 repetitions(a,b,c,d) in each combination of the 3 factors . it took place over 3 years.

```
if(!require(lmerTest)){install.packages("lmerTest")}
if(!require(lsmeans)){install.packages("lsmeans")}
if(!require(car)){install.packages("car")}

library(lmerTest)
library(lsmeans)
library(car)

year<-as.factor(c(rep("2012",32),rep("2013",32),rep("2014",32)))
Row_width<-as.factor(rep(c(rep("wide",16),rep("narrow",16)),3))
Fertilizer<-as.factor(rep(c(rep("Fert_x",8),rep("Fert_y",8)),6))
Variety<-as.factor(rep(c(rep("var_A",4),rep("Var_B",4)),12))
Repetition<-as.factor(rep(c("a","b","c","d"),24))
Yield<-(rnorm(96, mean=100, sd=10))

data1<-data.frame(year,Row_width,Fertilizer,Variety,Repetition,Yield)


#### mixed effect Model ####
model = lmer(Yield ~ Row_width + Fertilizer + Variety + (1|Repetition) + (1|year) ,data = data1, REML=TRUE) 
Anova(model)

lsmeans = lsmeans::lsmeans
leastsquare =lsmeans(model, pairwise ~ Row_width, adjust = "tukey")
cld(leastsquare, alpha=.05, Letters=letters, adjust="tukey")
```

Comment: Your model includes `year` as a random effect. What's your question? If you want it as a fixed effect use `+ year` instead of `+ (1|year)`.

Comment: Hi Gregor, my question is if i can simply add year as a random effect or if i need to integrate it into the model in another way ?

Comment: You can do either a fixed effect or a random effect. The question of which to do isn't a programming question, so it doesn't belong here. You could try asking at stats.stackexchange, [you should probably read this question on fixed vs random effects first](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/58900/7515).

Comment: Thanxs Gregor, didnt know that this page is only for programming!